# Filtering linq query by value

Tags: c#, linq

If I have the query below :-

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
            group data by new
            {
                InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                Code = "1",
                InvType = "I",
                Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                ChargeTotal = g.Sum(d => d.field<double>("Charge")
            };
```

...what is the best method of excluding rows where the sum of column ChargeTotal is zero? I'm assuming I have to use a `WHERE`, but I'm not sure where to place it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have many solutions because the `where` must be called after the `group by` (it depends on the groups), then:

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
             group data by new
             {
                 InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                 AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
             }
             into g
             let sum = g.Sum(d => d.field<double>("Charge"))  // Sum only computed once
             where sum != 0
             select new
             {
                 Code = "1",
                 InvType = "I",
                 Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                 InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                 ChargeTotal = sum
             };
```

To slightly improve performances (you have to test both to see if there is any performance improvement because it highly depends on the data), if d.field("Charge") is always >= 0, you can do:

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
             group data by new
             {
                 InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                 AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
             }
             into g
             where g.Any(d => d.field<double>("Charge") != 0)  
             select new
             {
                 Code = "1",
                 InvType = "I",
                 Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                 InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                 ChargeTotal = g.Sum(d => d.field<double>("Charge"))
             };
```